# sscanf reads one character instead of the entire string (mmap)

Tags: c, mmap

I was using memory mapping to "edit" one file and print the results to another, when I encountered this phenomenon. My understanding is that `sscanf` (similar to printf) reads a string until a whitespace or newline is encountered. This was exactly my tactic, when I used it on my `mmap`'d source file to filter out the comments and print everything else to second file. For a given argument of how the comment line starts (a string e.g. "#", "@","//", "whatever"), I used `sscanf` to check if a line began with that word. Much to my surprise it seems that when `mmap` is used, the pointer to that virtual memory isn't treated the same. (note the test printf right before the while loop).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static void     fatalError(char *message);

int     main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int     fd1, fd2;
    struct stat     stats;
    char    *source, *dest;


    assert(argc == 4);

    if ((fd1 = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY)) < 0) {
        if (errno == ENOENT)
            fatalError("First file nonexistent");
        else 
            fatalError("open error");
    }


    if ((fd2 = open(argv[2], O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP | S_IROTH)) < 0) {
        if (errno == EACCES)
            printf("Creating second file\n");
        else
            fatalError("open error");
    }


    if (fstat(fd1, &stats) < 0)
        fatalError("fstat error");

    if (lseek(fd2, stats.st_size-1, SEEK_SET) < 0)
        fatalError("lseek error");

    if (write(fd2, "", 1) != 1)
        fatalError("write error");


    if ((source = mmap(0, stats.st_size, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd1, 0)) == MAP_FAILED)
        fatalError("mmap failed");

    if ((dest = mmap(0, stats.st_size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd2, 0)) == MAP_FAILED)
        fatalError("mmap failed");

    char    word[100];
    int     flag, count;
    char    *tmp;

    tmp = source;

    char    test[50] = "firstWord will only be read by sscanf";
    sscanf(test, "%s", word);
    printf("%s\n", word);

    while ((count = sscanf(source, "%s", word)) > 0) {
        if (!flag) {
            // in comment
            if (!strcmp(word, argv[3])) {
                flag = 1;
                source += count;
                continue;
            }
            sprintf(dest, "%s", word);
            source += count;
        } else {
            // not in comment
            if (word[strlen(word) - 1] == '\n') {
                sprintf(dest, "\n");
                source += count;
            }

            source += count;

        }

    }

    source = tmp;

    if (munmap(source, stats.st_size) < 0)
        fatalError("munmap error");

    if (munmap(dest, stats.st_size) < 0)
        fatalError("munmap error");

    if (close(fd1) < 0)
        fatalError("close return");

    if (close(fd2) < 0)
        fatalError("close error");




    return 0;
}


static void     fatalError(char *message) {
    perror(message);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

The input file("#" as comment symbol):

```
npwhitespacea
asdasdasdasd
# asdasdasdasmdaosimda
asdasd
kmflsdkfms
#
oioiasjdoaisd
i
# asoidaosid
```

Comment: How are you creating your input file?  Are you **sure** it's not encoded and written as wide characters?  Can you do a hex or octal dump of the file contents?

Comment: Please read the docs when you use a function.  sscanf returns the number of items read (1), not the number of characters.

Comment: You also don't initialize `flag` before you test it the first time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`source += count;` is questionable code as it is the same as `source++;` for `count` is 1 here.

Likely on  a match, code should advance by the length of the string and not the conversion count.

```
  // in comment
  if (!strcmp(word, argv[3])) {
    flag = 1;
    // source += count;
    source += strlen(argv[3]);
    continue;
  }
```

---

Code is never true

`word[strlen(word) - 1] == '\n'` is never true because `sscanf(source, "%s", word)` will not put white-space into `word`.

---

> sscanf (similar to printf) reads a string until a whitespace or newline is encountered.

OP's generalization is too broad.  1) the "until" depends on the format.  2) With format `"%s"`, `sscanf()` reads white-spaces and skip other them, then its reads non-white-spaces and saves them. This continues until a whitespace (which include a `'\n'`) is found.  `sscanf()` differs from `scanf/fscanf` in this case as reading a *null character* by `scanf/fscanf` is read/saved just like any non-white-space.  With `sscanf()`, a *null character* is akin to an end-of-file.  It is not "read/saved", but does stop the scan.

---

OP's overall strategy have weaknesses.  OP is looking for *comment line*.  `"%s"` loses all awareness of `'\n'`.

Code could use the below to read a *line*, yet more work is needed for empty or very long lines.

```
char line[260];
int n = 0;
sscanf(source, "%259[^\n]%n", line, &n);
if (line > 0) {
  // success, now read potential \n or more line
  ...
} else {
  // read potential \n (a short line)
  ...
}

// process line

// next line
source += n;
```

---

Other issues may exist.

Answer (score 0):

`sscanf` reads until null `'\0'` character.